# Excel VBA: How to Use Nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Effectively I want to create an array where I can use types, and have it over time. So what this means is the goal is to have an array where I can call: `Array(At a period = 1).Name.Variable = the expected Value`. So I've been designing the array to look like:

```
    { Period1:{ 
               {A:{Revenue:5,ROE:5%},
                B:{Revenue:7,ROE:8%}
               }
      Period2:{ 
               {A:{Revenue:5,ROE:5%},
                B:{Revenue:7,ROE:8%}
                }
     }
```

I'm reading these values from an excel table that has the Names (A,B) with the respective values of Revenue and ROE. I'm then using these values to do something to them over time.

This is what I tried I get the following compile error: Only user-defined types in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type RelationshipArray
    Revenue As Double
    ROE As Double
End Type

Public Type RelationshipProductCategory
      Period As Integer
      A as variant 
      B as variant
End Type
'
'Private this As RelationshipArray
'
'Public Property Get Revenue(ByVal value As Double) As Double
'    Revenue = this.Revenue
'End Property
'
'Public Property Get ROE(ByVal value As Double) As Double
'    ROE = this.ROE
'End Property



Function GetRelationshipValues(ByVal Period As Integer, ByRef B As Variant, ByRef A As Variant) As RelationshipProductCategory
    GetRelationshipValues.Period = Period
    GetRelationshipValues.A = A
    GetRelationshipValues.B = B

End Function


Sub RelationshipIncomeCalculation()
Dim ar(10)
Dim A As RelationshipArray
Dim B As RelationshipArray


'this table value is analogous to Range("A2") just more robust for my use
A.Revenue = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "A", "Revenue", 0, 0)
A.ROE = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "A", "ROE", 0, 0)

B.Revenue = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "B", "Revenue", 0, 0)
B.ROE = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "BUSINESS DEPOSITS", "ROE", 0, 0)
ar(0) = GetRelationshipValues(0, A,B)
```

Comment: Is this sitting in a class?

Comment: Nope the sub is the main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that my answer still helps, but if you have already got over the problem, it would be great if you can mark this as answer if it is OK to you

Basically, you should not declare `RelationshipArray` and `RelationshipProductCategory` as a *Type*, but a *Class Module* instead (which is what the "user-defined types in public object modules" is referring to).

E.g. Right-click project and create a Class Module `RelationshipArray`, and paste these into it:

```
Public Revenue As Double
Public ROE As Double
```

And do the similar for `RelationshipProductCategory`.

To create a new instance of class module, you should do

```
dim v as RelationshipArray
set v = new RelationshipArray
```

Same for setting it to an array element:

```
Dim ar(10) as RelationshipArray
Set ar(0) = v
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetRelationshipValues(ByVal Period As Integer, ByRef B As Variant, ByRef A As Variant) As RelationshipProductCategory
    Dim rtn As RelationshipProductCategory
    Set rtn = New RelationshipProductCategory
    rtn.Period = Period
    Set rtn.A = A
    Set rtn.B = B
    Set GetRelationshipValues = rtn
End Function
Function TableValue(rel As String, prodasp As String, attr As String, v1 As Double, v2 As Double) As Double
    TableValue = Rnd
End Function

Sub RelationshipIncomeCalculation()
    Dim ar(10) as RelationshipProductCategory
    Dim A As RelationshipArray
    Dim B As RelationshipArray
    Set A = New RelationshipArray
    Set B = New RelationshipArray

    'this table value is analogous to Range("A2") just more robust for my use
    A.Revenue = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "A", "Revenue", 0, 0)
    A.ROE = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "A", "ROE", 0, 0)

    B.Revenue = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "B", "Revenue", 0, 0)
    B.ROE = TableValue("RelationShipIncomeInput", "BUSINESS DEPOSITS", "ROE", 0, 0)
    Set ar(0) = GetRelationshipValues(0, A, B)

    MsgBox "ar(0).A.Revenue = " & ar(0).A.Revenue
End Sub
```

I recommend you to know more about the difference between a Type and a Class Module. Basically, class modules are more useful IMO.

Comment: I had a very round about way to get this. I might end up implementing this.